# Why do 3 tables join produce duplicate rows?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 tables `Vehicletype, VehicleOwner, VehicleInformation`
in which `VtypeID` is the PK in `Vehicletype` and FK in `VehicleOwner` and `VehicleInformation`.

`Vehicletype` has 3 rows, `VehicleOwner` has 7 rows and `VehicleInformation` also has 7 rows.

When I join `Vehicletype` and `VehicleOwner`, I get accurate result with 7 records

[Accurate result in the result of 2 table joining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/113z9.jpg)

But when I join this two table with third table (`VehicleInformation`), I get duplicate rows

[Duplicate rows in the result of 3 tables joining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmVQU.jpg)

Please guide me to solve this problem

Comment: You haven't provided much information in order for us to help you,but `DISTINCT` keyword will remove the duplicates in this case

Comment: It's a little hard to say because your select statement only includes fields from VehicleOwner and VehicleType tables, but it is likely because there are rows of data relevant to your VehicleTypes in the VehicleInformation table. So for the '4 Wheeler' VehicleType there are likely three related rows in the VehicleInformation table. It's difficult to help you solve the problem as we don't know what it is you actually want to see as the result of your query? Could you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If you can provide all the 3 tables data, then it would be more easy to find the issue. Also, the most probable cause is that you will be having multiple matching VtypeIDs in your VehicleInformation table, causing cross join for such records.

Comment: Vehicletype:
VtypeID VehicleType
1 2 Wheeler
2 4 Wheeler
3 6 Wheeler

VehicleOwner:
OwnerName Gender VtypeID RegistrationNumber
Ata ul Haque Male 2 ADS-770
Aashir Ul Haque Male 1 HAE-3506
kashan male 2 HDDGGG44GG3
wonderwomen female 3 HKGHGEH4IU4
sohaib kjjflkjn 2 jgjk
kjgjk kjhkj 1 khjgj
new new 3 new

Comment: VehicleInformation:
VtypeID RegistrationNumber Color ChassisNumber EngineNumber RegistrationDate Model ManufacturedBy
2 ADS-770 Grey HJHHY666HH EEWIUI8IIOIO 2016-04-26 2002 Suzuki
1 HAE-3506 Black HAGAFT553YY HHHYYT666NJ 2012-01-01 2010 Honda
2 HDDGGG44GG3 red HHYWO93JJQ HHY3LOOIAY 4-4-2013 2010 Super Power
3 HKGHGEH4IU4 BLACK HDHD3U HDBDH333HH 7-7-2017 2000 JUSTICE LEAGE
2 jgjk kjgkjj ghjgjh kgkjgjkj kjgkjg 2012 jhhgjhgj
1 khjgj jjh jhfjhf hfhjm jhghhj 435 hgfhg
3 new new new new new 0 new

Comment: this is all data from 3 tables and I want to join these 3 tables to show vehicle type in my asp.net web app but getting duplicate records when i join these tables

Comment: accept
Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.
I just want to display vehicle type column consist (2 Wheeler, 4 Wheeler, 6 Wheeler) with VehicleOwner and VehicleInformation table in my web app.

Comment: table records
Vehicletype:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/axa6K.jpg

VehicleOwner:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSD6q.jpg

VehicleInformation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwOK0.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created sample data with 3 table Vehicletype, VehicleOwner, VehicleInformation in which typeID is PK.

/* Create a table */

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicletype(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);
CREATE TABLE VehicleOwner(OwnerId integer, InfoID integer, TypeId integer, Name text);
CREATE TABLE VehicleInformation(InfoId integer, OwnerId integer, TypeId integer, INfo text);
```

/* Create few records in Vehicletype table */

```
INSERT INTO Vehicletype VALUES(1,'TYPE1');
INSERT INTO Vehicletype VALUES(2,'TYPE2');
INSERT INTO Vehicletype VALUES(3,'TYPE3');
```

/* Create few records in VehicleOwner table */

```
INSERT INTO VehicleOwner VALUES(1,1,1,'NAME1');
INSERT INTO VehicleOwner VALUES(2,2,2,'NAME2');
INSERT INTO VehicleOwner VALUES(3,3,3,'NAME3');
INSERT INTO VehicleOwner VALUES(4,4,1,'NAME4');
INSERT INTO VehicleOwner VALUES(5,5,2,'NAME5');
INSERT INTO VehicleOwner VALUES(6,6,3,'NAME6');
INSERT INTO VehicleOwner VALUES(7,7,1,'NAME7');
```

/* Create few records in VehicleInformation table */

```
INSERT INTO VehicleInformation VALUES(1,1,1,'INFO1');
INSERT INTO VehicleInformation VALUES(2,2,2,'INFO2');
INSERT INTO VehicleInformation VALUES(3,3,3,'INFO3');
INSERT INTO VehicleInformation VALUES(4,4,1,'INFO4');
INSERT INTO VehicleInformation VALUES(5,5,2,'INFO5');
INSERT INTO VehicleInformation VALUES(6,6,3,'INFO6');
INSERT INTO VehicleInformation VALUES(7,7,1,'INFO7');

COMMIT;
```

/* Display all the records from the table */

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicletype;
SELECT * FROM VehicleOwner;
SELECT * FROM VehicleInformation;
```

This join will give you the unique result from your data.

```
select *
from  Vehicletype vt,VehicleOwner vo, VehicleInformation vi
where 1=1
and vt.id=vo.typeid
and vt.id=vi.typeid
and vo.ownerid=vi.ownerid
and vo.infoid=vi.infoid
and vo.typeid=vi.typeid;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
but i do not need all column selection I need 
`select VehicleOwner.OwnerID, OwnerName, Gender, VType, VehicleInformation.RegistrationNumber, RegistrationDate, ChassisNumber, EngineNumber, Model, ManufacturedBy
from  VehicleType vt,VehicleOwner vo, VehicleInformation vi
where 1=1
and vt.id=vo.typeid
and vt.id=vi.typeid
and vo.ownerid=vi.ownerid
and vo.infoid=vi.infoid
and vo.typeid=vi.typeid;`

Comment: but this query giving me error
 **Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "VehicleOwner.OwnerID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "VehicleInformation.RegistrationNumber" could not be bound.**

Comment: @AaShirHaq instead of VehicleOwner.OwnerID use vo.ownerid, vo is alias of table VehicleOwner

Answer (score 0):

Let's say owners O1 and O2 both have vehicle type V1. Now if there are three records in the vehicle information table, I1, I2 and I3, that have vehicle type V1, then when you create your joins you will get rows in the output showing:

```
V1, O1, I1
V1, O1, I2
V1, O1, I3
V1, O2, I1
V1, O2, I2
V1, O2, I3
```

You will see what's going on more clearly if you include all the PK columns in your output.